# Solving HTTP Error 400: Bad Request with working links in Google Chrome

Tags: python, request, urllib, user-agent

I know this has been asked in many forms already, but I can't seem to find my answer and hope to receive some help here. 
I try to download files that are stored behind a list of urls..

I've found following function that should do what I want:

```
import os.path
import urllib.request
import requests

for link in links:
    link = link.strip()
    name = link.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    filename = os.path.join('downloads', name)

    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        print('Downloading: ' + filename)
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, filename)
        except Exception as inst:
            print(inst)
            print('  Encountered unknown error. Continuing.')
```

I always receive: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request.

I tried to set user-agents to fake a browser visit (I use Google Chrome), but it did not help at all. The links work if copied in the browser, hence I wonder how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.

The problem was that the urls contained white spaces, which apparently can not be read in properly by `urllib.request`. The solution is to first parse the urls into quotes and then call the quoted url.

This is the working code for all that run into the same problem:

```
import os.path
import urllib.request
import requests
import urllib.parse

for link in urls:
    link = link.strip()
    name = link.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    filename = os.path.join(name)
    quoted_url = urllib.parse.quote(link, safe=":/")

    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        print('Downloading: ' + filename)
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(quoted_url, filename)
        except Exception as inst:
            print(inst)
            print('  Encountered unknown error. Continuing.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Spaces have to be quoted. I've used [quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) function to quote filename in your link. Also I've used [rindex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rindex) to cut last part in url path. There is [urlsplit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit) and [urlunsplit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunsplit) functions which should be used instead of string operations, but .. I'm too lazy :D

```
import os.path
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import quote

links = ['https://undpgefpims.org/attachments/6222/216410/1717887/1724973/6222_4NC_3BUR_Macedonia_Final ProDoc 30 July 2018.doc', 'https://undpgefpims.org/attachments/6214/216405/1719672/1729436/6214_4NC_Niger_ProDoc  final for DoA.doc']

for link in links:
    link = link.strip()
    name = link.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    filename = os.path.join('downloads', name)

    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        print('Downloading: ' + filename)
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(link[:link.rindex('/') + 1] + quote(link[link.rindex('/') + 1:]), filename)
        except Exception as inst:
            print(inst)
            print('  Encountered unknown error. Continuing.')
```

Comment: Thank you Olvin! Just in the same moment I found my mistake and added the working code as an answer. I really appreciate your help though.